# How print things in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to get NetBeans to print full name of customer with capital letters for the start of the names but I'm only get initials

```
package question1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {
      
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       String First;
       String Second;
       String Fullname;
      char UpperCaseFirst;
      char UpperCaseSecond;
      Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    
       System.out.println ("enter First name");
       First=input.next();
       
       System.out.println ("enter Second name");
       Second=input.next();
       
       UpperCaseFirst=Character.toUpperCase(First.charAt(0));
       UpperCaseSecond=Character.toUpperCase(Second.charAt(0));
       Fullname=UpperCaseFirst+" "+UpperCaseSecond;
      
     
    System.out.println("custoemr:\n");
        System.out.println(Fullname);
```

Comment: `String UpperCaseFirst=Character.toUpperCase(First.charAt(0)) + First.substring(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Java variable naming conventions, `firstName`, `lastName` and `fullName` (not `Firstname`, that looks like a `class`). Second, you shouldn't declare your variables until you need to. And you can use `String.substring(int)` to get the rest of the `String`. You can also use `String` formatting, with `String.format`, `System.out.printf` or both. Don't forget to call `toLowerCase()` at some point (if you want consistency). Like,

```
System.out.println("enter First name");
String firstName = input.next();

System.out.println("enter Second name");
String lastName = input.next();

String fullName = String.format("%c%s %c%s",
        Character.toUpperCase(firstName.charAt(0)),
        firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase(),
        Character.toUpperCase(lastName.charAt(0)),
        lastName.substring(1).toLowerCase());
System.out.printf("customer:%n%s%n", fullName);
```